# Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime' not found

Tags: magento-1, catalog, fatal-error

when trying to edit a product in admin I suddenly got this error:

> PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime' not found
>   in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 146

I tried to google it but was unable to find a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the file exists under /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Datetime.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Varien
 * @package     Varien_Data
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Varien data selector form element
 *
 * @category   Varien
 * @package    Varien_Data
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some core files are missing in your Magento instance. Check whether `/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Datetime.php` does exists in your code base.

Here is the link for latest [**Datetime.php**](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Datetime.php). You can create a new file and place that code in it.

But if the file is missing, then the most important thing which you need to check is how that file get missed. Make sure such "core hacks" do not happen anymore.